# Javascript Class not recognizing new Instance Property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, web-audio-api

I'm trying to use soundtouch.js to preserve the pitch of audio in the browser, but am having some trouble with an instance property not being recognized by the audio context during an event.

Here's my basic React UI:

[image: React UI]

**App.js**

These are the functions in my React component handling the input ranges and getting a Playback instance:

```
const playbackEngine = new PlaybackEngine({
            emitter: emitter,
            pitch: pitch,
            tempo: tempo,
    });

const handlePitchChange = (event) => {
        pitch = event.target.value;
        document.getElementById('pitch-value').innerHTML = `Pitch (${pitch}x)`;
        emitter.emit('pitch');
        playbackEngine.pitch = event.target.value;
}

const handleTempoChange = (event) => {
    tempo = event.target.value;
    document.getElementById('tempo-value').innerHTML = `Tempo (${tempo}x)`;
    emitter.emit('tempo');
    playbackEngine.tempo = event.target.value;
}

const handleSeek = (event) => {
    percent = parseFloat(event.target.value);
    document.getElementById('seek-value').value = percent;
    playbackEngine.seekPercent(percent);
    playbackEngine.play();
}
```

**PlaybackEngine.js**

```
const {SimpleFilter, SoundTouch} = require('./soundtouch');

const BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

export default class PlaybackEngine {
    constructor({emitter, pitch, tempo}) {
        this.emitter = emitter;
        this.context = new AudioContext();
        this.scriptProcessor = this.context.createScriptProcessor(BUFFER_SIZE, 2, 2);

        this.scriptProcessor.onaudioprocess = e => {
            const l = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
            const r = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(1);
            const framesExtracted = this.simpleFilter.extract(this.samples, BUFFER_SIZE);
            if (framesExtracted === 0) {
                this.emitter.emit('stop');
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < framesExtracted; i++) {
                l[i] = this.samples[i * 2];
                r[i] = this.samples[i * 2 + 1];
            }
        };

        this.soundTouch = new SoundTouch();
        this.soundTouch.pitch = pitch;
        this.soundTouch.tempo = tempo;

        this.duration = undefined;
    }

    get pitch() {
        return this.soundTouch.pitch;
    }
    set pitch(pitch) {
        this.soundTouch.pitch = pitch;
    }

    get tempo() {
        return this.soundTouch.tempo;
    }
    set tempo(tempo) {
        this.soundTouch.tempo = tempo;
    }

    decodeAudioData(data) {
        return this.context.decodeAudioData(data);
    }

    setBuffer(buffer) {
        const bufferSource = this.context.createBufferSource();
        bufferSource.buffer = buffer;

        this.samples = new Float32Array(BUFFER_SIZE * 2);
        this.source = {
            extract: (target, numFrames, position) => {
                this.emitter.emit('time', (position / this.context.sampleRate));
                const l = buffer.getChannelData(0);
                const r = buffer.getChannelData(1);
                for (let i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
                    target[i * 2] = l[i + position];
                    target[i * 2 + 1] = r[i + position];
                }
                return Math.min(numFrames, l.length - position);
            },
        };
        this.simpleFilter = new SimpleFilter(this.source, this.soundTouch);
        this.emitter.emit('buffered', this.simpleFilter);

        this.duration = buffer.duration;
        this.emitter.emit('duration', buffer.duration);
    }

    play() {
        this.scriptProcessor.connect(this.context.destination);
    }

    pause() {
        this.scriptProcessor.disconnect(this.context.destination);
    }

    seekPercent(percent) {
        if (this.simpleFilter !== undefined) {
            this.simpleFilter.sourcePosition = Math.round(
                percent / 100 * this.duration * this.context.sampleRate
            );
        }
    }
}
```

App.js calls `playbackEngine.setBuffer()` once the audio file is ready, which adds this.simpleFilter as an instance property. The audio plays correctly, but when I call `seekPercent()` in my handleSeek function, it is undefined. Consequently, the `onaudioprocess` crashes because of this, with the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extract' of undefined
    at ScriptProcessorNode.PitchEngine.scriptProcessor.onaudioprocess
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What did you mean to do with `this.simpleFilter;`? That doesn't look right.

Comment: Oof, that was from a previous console.log() to find out what was happening. Fixed post

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

The problem was that the audio's arrayBuffer was being placed in `setBuffer()` during the component's `useEffect` with an empty dependency array (`componentDidMount`-style). So when events occurred on the instantiated playback engine, they were as if only the instance properties before the `useEffect` was called existed. Fixed it by defining event listeners within the `useEffect` on my input controls.